# Is there any non-root disk IO monitor software available on Ubuntu?

Tags: disk, monitoring, io

Is there any disk IO monitor software available on Ubuntu that can show what processes are reading/writing at what speed and that I can install and run without `sudo`?

I know there is `iotop`, but I can't run it because I'm not a super user. There's `iostat` which seems to not need root but it doesn't give very much info either.

Answer (score 3):

No. You can monitor your own activity in the directories you have access to, but by definition, if you want to monitor I/O activity on the entire filesystem, you will need `sudo` access since you need to monitor things your regular user has no permission to access.

So there is no tool that will solve it for you. In fact, if such a tool existed, it would mean there is a fundamental and very serious bug in the permissions system.

If this is something you need to do, talk to your system administrator and ask that your user be given permission to run `iotop` as root.